# Load_FILE is not Inserting/updating image

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to Insert/update/upload image into MySQL table using the following record but I get `0 rows affected` message

```
 UPDATE `table_name`
 SET Image_Field = LOAD_FILE('C:\Users\computer_Name\Desktop\image_name.jpg')
 WHERE Brand_Name LIKE 'image_name%'
```

Comment: What does the table look like? What data is in it? What do you mean ba "insert/update"? This is just update. BTW, consider using a primary key.

Comment: @zvone What if `Image_Field` is Blank? `LOAD_FILE` doesnt work

Comment: Do you have the FILE privilege?What is the size of `max_allowed_packet `?

Comment: @Mihai `max_allowed_packet = 16776192` and IT did update once 29 records but images were not there when i `echo` the tire image also shows me `[BLOB - 0 B]` in mYSQL side. Is the path have to be `backslash` or `forwardslash`?